# Call SharePoint Online rest api from console c# app with modern auth

Tags: sharepoint

1. I am trying to call sharepoint search api from console app, in tenant only Modern authentication is active.
   So i created Azure App and give there api permission ("AllSites.Read", "Sites.Search.All","Sites.Read.All", "Files.Read.All").
2. I am able to get auth token , but getting unauthorized error during api call , below is my code

   var defaultRequestHeaders = HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
   if (defaultRequestHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Any(m =>
   m.MediaType ==
   "application/json"))
   {
   HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
   MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose"));
   }
   defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer",
   accessToken);
   HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(webApiUrl);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)

Answer (score 0):

After nuget upgraded with Microsoft.identiy.model version verion v 4.4.1. Now able to fix this issue.